# Adjusting letterspacing in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, kerning, letterspacing

I need to adjust the letterspacing of the font I'm using. I'm currently using the font like this:

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\definefontfeature[default][default][protrusion=quality,expansion=quality]
\setupalign[hz,hanging]
\setmainfont[Minion Pro]
\setmathfont[Minion Pro]

\starttext
Foobar
\stoptext
```

What can I do, as [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) is unavailable?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, with `\starttext` and ending with `\stoptext`.

Comment: MWE from typo-krn.mkiv: (i) `{\setcharacterkerning[extrakerning]\input davis\relax}`. You can change the distance between letters using `\definecharacterkerning [extrakerning] [\c!factor=.125]`; (ii) `\setuphead[section][style=\sca,textstyle={\kerncharacters[.5]}] \section{Section}`

Comment: @Aditya (ii) Does exactly what I wanted, but it looks like it breaks the line breaking algorithm: http://imgur.com/PnsQ67A (1) Has the same problem. Is this a bug in luatex?

Comment: It also breaks aligning to the grid.

Comment: Please create minimal example.

Comment: No news on an updated example, so 'unclear'